# Azure synapse pipeline date format issue

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am currently using Azure synapse pipeline with Copy Activity which connects to the source ADLS which has CSV formatted file and in Sink to another directory converting to Parquet format.

In the CSV formatted files, there is a date Column with example 01/08/2023 and after converting to Parquet and when I create an external table on top of it the date column changes to 08-01-2023.

I tried using the mapping option in Copy Activity and for the column date I tried using datetime and datetimeoffset datatype but it didn't properly work.

I am still confused why the parquet format understands it in a different way. Is there a solution to keep the date format as YYY-MM-dd format in parquet file or in External table.

[Source CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/540fv.png)

[Target Parquet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpFtS.png)

The position of month and date changes.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a solution to keep the date format as YYY-MM-dd format in parquet file or in External table.

When you read the data from the parquet file you need to set the column data type and for date data al the datatype are in `yyyy-dd-MM` format also we cand convert it while creating the table.

The workaround can be when you will execute select statement on the table at time convert it into your desired format by using below query:

```sql
select date as CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 101) from table
```

or you can create a view based on that table and convert the date into your desired format :

```sql
CREATE  VIEW [dbo].[View1]
AS  SELECT ID,PATIENTNAME ,
CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 101) as Datedd FROM table

select * from view1
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: The problem is I am using a reusable script which creates external table. In the CSV format the date looks like 01/08/2023 [ dd/MM/YYYY ] but when it converts to Parquet and when I see the data through an external table the date changes to 2023-01-08 [ YYYY-dd-MM].                                                                                                                          Source  format: dd/MM/YYYY                                                                                            Target  format [changes dd and MM]: YYYY-dd-MM

Comment: Added source csv and target parquet snapshot for reference.

Comment: you can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=parquet#date_format--datetime_format)  `YYYY-dd-MM` id default date format for date data type you cnat convert it while creating table.

Answer (score 0):

Is your external table or the copy process specifying the date column as *type* date?  Have you tried using *type* varchar(10)